# How to change shape color on tap

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to implement the logic to change the shape color on tap. I tried to modify the [example for changing the shape on tap](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/animating-simple-shapes-with-animatabledata) as follows:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PathView: View {
    @State private var insetAmount: CGFloat = 50
    @State private var fillColor: UIColor = UIColor.white
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {
            geometry in
            ZStack {
                Trapezoid(insetAmount: insetAmount, fillColor: fillColor)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.insetAmount = CGFloat.random(in: 10...90)
                                let demoColors = [UIColor.blue, UIColor.green, UIColor.red]
                                self.fillColor = demoColors.randomElement() ?? UIColor.white
                            }
            }.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .topLeading)
            
        }
    }
}

struct Trapezoid: Shape {
    var insetAmount: CGFloat
    var fillColor: UIColor

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: insetAmount, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - insetAmount, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.maxY))
        path.closeSubpath()
        fillColor.setFill()
        UIColor.white.setStroke()
        path.fill()
        return path
   }
}
```

The path, however, is black and the line path.fill() displays a warning:

> Result of call to 'fill(style:)' is unused

Does anyone know how to set the color property of shape and change it on tap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `fill` should be applied to `Shape`.

Here is possible solution (tested with Xcode 12)

```
struct PathView: View {
    @State private var insetAmount: CGFloat = 50
    @State private var fillColor: UIColor = UIColor.white
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {
            geometry in
            ZStack {
                Trapezoid(insetAmount: insetAmount)
                            .fill(Color(fillColor))           // << here !!
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.insetAmount = CGFloat.random(in: 10...90)
                                let demoColors = [UIColor.blue, UIColor.green, UIColor.red]
                                self.fillColor = demoColors.randomElement() ?? UIColor.white
                            }
            }.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .topLeading)

        }
    }
}

struct Trapezoid: Shape {
    var insetAmount: CGFloat

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: insetAmount, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - insetAmount, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.maxY))
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
   }
}
```